# Animate navigation bar barTintColor change in iOS10 not working

Tags: ios, swift2, ios10

I upgraded to XCode 8.0 / iOS 10 and now the color change animation of my navigation bar is not working anymore, it changes the color directly without any animation.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = currentSection.color!
})
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To animate navigationBar’s color change in iOS10 you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` after setting color inside animation block.

Example code:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { 
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Also I want to inform that Apple [doesn’t officialy support](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60258) animations in such properties like barTintColor, so that method can break at any time.

> If you call -layoutIfNeeded on the navigation bar during the animation
>   block it should update its background properties, but given the nature
>   of what these properties do, there really hasn't ever been any kind of
>   guarantee that you could animate any of them.

Comment: It works indeed, but the title of my navigation bar is also animating (I don't set the title in the "animateWithDuration" function. The title move from the top left to the center of the navigation bar when the color change is animating...

Comment: @Tiois, I think that problem is only in your project. Possible you set title in same layout cycle, check all properties that you change in your ViewController. I have created test project and title stays at place, you can check it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42855950/test.zip

Comment: You were right, after setting the title, I now call layoutIfNeeded() on the navigation and and then I call the UIView.animateWithDuration function with layoutIfNeeded() and it's working fine! Thanks.

Comment: You just saved my day

Comment: `layoutIfNeeded()` works amazingly, Thank you for saving the day. :)

Answer (score 4):

### Interactive animation

[image: Interactive animation]

Define a protocol:

```
/// Navigation bar colors for `ColorableNavigationController`, called on `push` & `pop` actions
public protocol NavigationBarColorable: UIViewController {
    var navigationTintColor: UIColor? { get }
    var navigationBarTintColor: UIColor? { get }
}

public extension NavigationBarColorable {
    var navigationTintColor: UIColor? { return nil }
}
```

Define a custom `NavigationController` subclass:

```
class AppNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        if let colors = rootViewController as? NavigationBarColorable {
            setNavigationBarColors(colors)            
        }
    }
    
    private var previousViewController: UIViewController? {
        guard viewControllers.count > 1 else {
            return nil
        }
        return viewControllers[viewControllers.count - 2]
    }
    
    override open func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        if let colors = viewController as? NavigationBarColorable {
            setNavigationBarColors(colors)
        }
               
        super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
    }
    
    override open func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        if let colors = previousViewController as? NavigationBarColorable {
            setNavigationBarColors(colors)
        }
                        
        // Let's start pop action or we can't get transitionCoordinator()
        let popViewController = super.popViewController(animated: animated)
        
        // Secure situation if user cancelled transition
        transitionCoordinator?.animate(alongsideTransition: nil, completion: { [weak self] context in
            guard let `self` = self else { return }

            guard let colors = self.topViewController as? NavigationBarColorable else { return }
            self.setNavigationBarColors(colors)
        })
        
        return popViewController
    }
    
    override func popToRootViewController(animated: Bool) -> [UIViewController]? {
        if let colors = rootViewController as? NavigationBarColorable {
            setNavigationBarColors(colors)
        }
        
        let controllers = super.popToRootViewController(animated: animated)
        
        return controllers
    }
    
    private func setNavigationBarColors(_ colors: NavigationBarColorable) {
        
        if let tintColor = colors.navigationTintColor {
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                .foregroundColor : tintColor
            ]
            navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
        }
        
        navigationBar.barTintColor = colors.navigationBarTintColor
    }
}
```

Now you can conform to `NavigationBarColorable` in any controller inside the `AppNavigationController` and give it any color you want.

```
extension FirstViewController: NavigationBarColorable {
    public var navigationBarTintColor: UIColor? { UIColor.red }
    public var navigationTintColor: UIColor? { UIColor.white }
}

extension SecondViewController: NavigationBarColorable {
    public var navigationBarTintColor: UIColor? { UIColor.blue }
    public var navigationTintColor: UIColor? { UIColor.orange }
}
```

Don't forget to implement this useful extension:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
        return viewControllers.first
    }
}
```

Comment: The best answer ever! Thanks.