# Update UIBarButtonItem within view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to update `UIBarButtonItem` tint color from a view controller but nothing has changed. Can't we access the `UIBarButtonItem` within view controller using `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.8 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^ {
        //button.alpha = .01;  //don't animate alpha to 0, otherwise you won't be able to interact with it
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];
```

Comment: have you create `UIBarButton` from coding or storyboard ?

Comment: are you trying to set color or animate its change?

Comment: It seems that tint animation not working properly. [See solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515313/animate-navigation-bar-bartintcolor-change-in-ios10-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your problem by making outlet of UIBarButtonItem. It is working fine. You can set the tint color by direct refrence.

Here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var addItem: UIBarButtonItem!
var  username = UITextField()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

@IBAction func addItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 20) {

        self.addItem.tintColor = UIColor.red
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let addButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
addButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
addButton.tintColor = UIColor.gray
let addMoreItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: addButton)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addMoreItem
```

it may be work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *btnBack = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[btnback setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(onClickBtnBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

also you can set background color and text color.